# $C^1[a,b]$ with norm $\left \| f \right \|=(\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}(t)dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not banach spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Is $C^1[a,b]$ with any of the norms $\left \| f \right \|_2=(\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}(t)dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and  $\left \| f \right \|_1=(\int_{a}^{b}\left | f(t) \right |)$ a Banach space?

I appreciate if you can suggest me ideas or bibliography;
I know that these can be completed by Sobolev, but I need to see that they are not Banach.

Comment: What the hell is "Hi please a dude" supposed to mean or add to that question?

Comment: @ClementC.: This is just a wild guess, but "duda" is "doubt" in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a function $f \in C[a,b]$ that is not in $C^1$ and a sequence $\{f_n\}$  of $C^1$ functions that converges uniformly to $f$.  Then $\{f_n\}$ will be Cauchy in either norm, but not convergent in either norm to a function in $C^1$.